# MVC 4 minvalue validation in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, nhibernate

I'm using NHiberante & MVC 4 and in my View I've this:

```
<div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumOfTransporters)</div>
```

I want to validate this field against a minvlaue. So the editor field accepts only numbers between 1 and higher.
As von v. said, I used:

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
public int NumOfTransporters { get; set; }
```

But still not working:
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use data annotation, you can use the Range attribute to specify the min value and then just set the max allowable value.

```
// in this example you set 100 as the min. value
// and virtually say there's no max value
[Range(100, int.MaxValue)]
public int NumOfTransporters {get;set;}
```

**UPDATE**:

> So the editor field accepts only numbers between 1 and 100.

Then do it like this

```
[Range(1, 100)]
public int NumOfTransporters {get;set;}
```

And if you want this validation to kick in on the client-side, make sure you have reference to the ff:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"/>
```

Comment: It's not working, I wanted to validate against a minvalue instead minlenght, I've updated the question.

Comment: Yes, I see you updated your question, please see my updated answer

Comment: See my updated answer again, I think you did not reference the unobtrusive script

Comment: Thank you von v. the script refs were missing.

Answer (score 1):

dear friend you have your poco class or your model for the aboue code so go to you model class and 
define annotation for your propery 
like

```
[StringLength(5)]
public int NumOfTransporters {get;set;}
```

the number depend on your requirments

Answer (score 0):

Use this validation property in your Model

```
[Range(0, Double.PositiveInfinity)]
public int NumOfTransporters {get;set;}
```